# Show Image Dynamically in ScrollPane JavaFx

Tags: javafx

I want to add Multiple images in Scollpane by clicking button i try below code but it will not display image any idea about that?

```
@FXML private void OnClick(ActionEvent ae)
{
  getGalleryView();
}
public void getGalleryView()
{
  ScrolPane sp=new ScroPane();
Hbox hb=new Hbox();
Image [] images=new Image[5];
ImageView []pics=new ImageView[5];
final String [] imageNames = new String [] {"fw1.jpg", "fw2.jpg",
    "fw3.jpg", "fw4.jpg", "fw5.jpg"};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageNames[i]));
        pics[i] = new ImageView(images[i]);
        pics[i].setFitWidth(100);
        pics[i].setPreserveRatio(true);
        hb.getChildren().add(pics[i]);
        sp.setContent(hb);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scrollpane to the scene:

```
@FXML private void OnClick(ActionEvent ae)
{
  getGalleryView(ae);
}
public void getGalleryView(ActionEvent ae)
{
  ScrolPane sp=new ScroPane();
  Hbox hb=new Hbox();
  Image [] images=new Image[5];
  ImageView []pics=new ImageView[5];
  final String [] imageNames = new String [] {"fw1.jpg", "fw2.jpg",
    "fw3.jpg", "fw4.jpg", "fw5.jpg"};

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageNames[i]));
        pics[i] = new ImageView(images[i]);
        pics[i].setFitWidth(100);
        pics[i].setPreserveRatio(true);
        hb.getChildren().add(pics[i]);
        sp.setContent(hb);

    }

    Scene scene = ((Node) ae.getSource()).getScene();
    ((Pane) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(sp);
}
```

I assumed here that your root node is a Pane or one of its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

ScrolPane sp=new ScroPane(); error?

**EDIT:**
I was developing similar method. Mine works fine. You can check if you want to.

```
    private List<String> listFileNames(File folder) throws NullPointerException{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory())
            listFileNames(file);
        else {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
            list.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
    return list;
}

private void insertImages(List<String> list, Hero thisHero) {
    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;
    for (String path:list) {
        String fullPath = "file:"+thisHero.getHeroClass().getFile()+"\\"+path;
        ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton();
        button.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
        button.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(fullPath)));
        grid.add(button,column,row);
        column++;
        if (column == 5) {
            row++;
            column = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I can write more if you want. I use Lists because of it's ease of adding items.

You can use first method to just get all file names to list, from your folder filled with image files.

Second method does the job of making new ImageViews filled with ToggleButtons with graphic. I just changed the concept to buttons, so sorry about my laziness of not changing code to exactly fit your needs.

Path is the exact file name, `thisHero.getHeroClass().getFile()` returns path to the directory which contains this image.

`grid.add(button, column, row)` adds this button to the grid pane which i made before. It's my app, so sorry for not sharing all the code, but i thought that this snippet could be usefull.

**EDIT2:** You could also provide us with error information if there is any.